# My player dies touching any object with box collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to do a game and I want my player to jump from an object to another and when it touches the ground to die. My player dies when he touch anything , how can I make him die just when it touches the ground? This is my code bellow

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move2d : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float playerSpeed;  //allows us to be able to change speed in Unity
    public Vector2 jumpHeight;
    public bool isDead = false;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isDead) { return; }
        transform.Translate(playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);  //makes player run

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))  //makes player jump
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpHeight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        isDead = true;
        rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        GameController.Instance.Die();
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a tag to your ground gameobject. 
Your new OnCollisionEnter2D would look like this.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision){

if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("ground")) // this will return true if the collision gameobject has ground tag on it.
{
    isDead = true;
    rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    GameController.Instance.Die();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

So in the method `OnCollisionEnter2D()`, whatever code is inside there will be triggered *every* time, regardless of what hit it. However, you can retrieve data about the collision to determine if it hit your ground. The best way to do this is using Unity's [layer system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TagManager.html).

First, you will want to create a layer (going to Project Settings > Tags and Layers. Be sure to remember which number was to the left of your layer's name) for all of your ground pieces and then should assign them to that layer. The when you collide with something, you can check if it is on that layer by using an `if` statement, like this.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    // Foo represents the number of the layer that the ground is assigned to.
    if (collision.collider.gameObject.layer == foo)
    {
        isDead = true;
        rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        GameController.Instance.Die();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I tag the layer ground , foo will be write like : ground, 0 ? or "ground" , 0